# How to Programaticly Slide an object from right to left into a Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, animation

Using `Silverlight`, `XAML` and `C#`, how do I programaticly slide an `Object/UserControl` from right to left into my view.

The problem I have is the VideoPlayer is still on screen from the begining. I set the start grid point to be Grid Column 9 but it still displays even though I only have 8 grid cols.

Im using a grid that has an **8 x 8** equal grid layout like so;

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row0" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row1" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row2" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row3" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row4" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row5" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row6" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="Row7" Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I have set the VideoPlayer to start at Grid.Col 9 but it is still showing of Col 8

The Current XAML of the player is

```
        <Controls:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.RowSpan="6"
            Grid.Column="9" <-- I wanted it off the grid but it still shows on col 8
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="15"                    
               />
```

I currently have

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="slideInVideo">
               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="videoPlayer"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Column"
                        From="8" To="5" Duration="00:00:10"/>

        </Storyboard>
```

Comment: What's wrong? What doesn't work? You've not asked your question! you've just given the requirements

Comment: OK ill update my question

Answer (score 1):

There are number of problems with your approach.

- First of all AFAIK you cant set an element to position in column `9` when you don't have 9 columns.
- Do note that `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties points to index which is zero based.
- Last but not least; Target should be `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)"` note the parenthesis, it is required for animating attached properties.

Comment: Great thanks, so how would I position the object off the grid

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I think not possible without using margin. I'll suggest you to hide it initially and start from `Column7` because setting off the grid is same as hiding from end user's perspective

Comment: Good point. I'll keep playing and if I find a solution I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in behaviors that are available within the expression interactivity and interactions namespaces

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"
```

More info here ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724013(v=expression.40).aspx

Things like the `FluidMoveBehavior` and the `ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect` can help you give the appearance of elements moving in from the side of the screen when they're loaded (or on other state changes).